# Using SharedPreferences by Provider on application startup

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have 2 startup page, I want run PgStartupNew if I haven't any value under "login" in shared preferences. But I can't do this, because SharedPreferences is not init yet. How I can avid this problem?

main.dart

```dart
        class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            // Provider<Future>(create: (_) => Future.value(42)),
            Provider<MySharedPreferences>(
                create: (_) => MySharedPreferences.create()),
            Provider<User>(create: (_) => User.create()),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: MyStyle.getThemeData(),
            title: 'TestApp',
            home: PgSelectStartup(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class PgSelectStartup extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return (Provider.of<MySharedPreferences>(context).read("login") ==
                null)
            ? PgStartupNew()
            : PgStartupLogin();
      }
    }
```

my_shared_preferences.dart

```
 String? read(String key) {
    return prefs.getString(key) ?? null;
  }
```

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building PgSelectStartup(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<MySharedPreferences>]):
The method 'getString' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getString("login")
```

I try add one extra call read() method before return from build and try force reinit SharedPrefs, but it still not working. EVERY first call to read() in class PgSelectStartup failing, because prefs == null.
How I can fix it? How to use "Widget build(BuildContext context)" when prefs is already init?
I found some cases how to do it, but none working in my case, where I use SharedPrefs on startup, and moreover using it via MultiProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access shared preferences at start up you need to either initialize it before `runApp` is invoked in `main`:

```
await MySharedPreferences.create();
// Initialize all needed asynchronous singletons.

runApp(MyApp());
```

or use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thank You, finally I fix it using FutureBuilder, fixed code below

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix it using FutureBuilder, new code:

```dart
class PgSelectStartup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of<MySharedPreferences>(context).myNewInitSync(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return (Provider.of<MySharedPreferences>(context)
                      .read("login") ==
                  null)
              ? PgStartupNew()
              : PgStartupLogin();
        } else {
          return Column(
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And new method in MySharedPreferences:

```dart
//old:
  static void myNewInit() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
// new:
  Future<SharedPreferences> myNewInitSync() {
    return prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```